# near duplicate detection python sql

Tags: python, sql, duplicates, cluster-analysis, anagram

I have a huge data set which contains shipper/supplier names from different sources and are having near duplicate values in it.
I tried so many different techniques available on the internet but none of them were quit satisfying or was too slow for this huge data.

I found this [openrefine GitHub repo](https://gist.github.com/cjdd3b/0386f139bb953f046c6e) for  fingerprinting algorithms and I added some more code and it solved my purpose.
Have a look.

My dataset something looks like this...

[image: Supplier Names Uncleaned]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re, string
import pandas as pd
from unidecode  import unidecode
from collections import defaultdict

# clean the text before processing
def cleansing_special_characters(txt):
    seps = [' ',';',':','.','`','~',',','*','#','@','|','\\','-','_','?','%','!','^','(',')','[',']','{','}','$','=','+','"','<','>',"'",' AND ', ' and ']
    default_sep = seps[0]
    txt = str(txt)
    for sep in seps[1:]:
        if sep == " AND " or sep == " and ":
            txt = txt.upper()
            txt = txt.replace(sep, ' & ')
        else:
            txt = txt.upper()
            txt = txt.replace(sep, default_sep)
    try :
        list(map(int,txt.split()))
        txt = 'NUMBERS'
    except:
        pass
    txt = re.sub(' +', ' ', txt)
    temp_list = [i.strip() for i in txt.split(default_sep)]
    temp_list = [i for i in temp_list if i]
    return " ".join(temp_list)


punctuation = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation))

class fingerprinter(object):
    
    # __init__function
    def __init__(self, string):
        self.string = self._preprocess(string)
        
    
    # strip leading, trailing spaces and to lower case
    def _preprocess(self, string):
        return punctuation.sub('',string.strip().lower())
    
        
    def _latinize(self, string):
        return unidecode(string)
#         return unidecode(string.decode('utf-8'))
    
    def _unique_preserve_order(self,seq):
        seen = set()
        seen_add = seen.add
        return [x for x in seq if not (x in seen or seen_add(x))]

    
    #-####################################################
    def get_fingerprint(self):
        return self._latinize(' '.join(self._unique_preserve_order(sorted(self.string.split()))))
    
    
    def get_ngram_fingerprint(self, n=1):
        return self._latinize(''.join(self._unique_preserve_order(sorted([self.string[i:i + n] for i in range(len(self.string) - n +1)]))))
    
    

# read excel file
df = pd.read_excel('Input_File.xlsx')

#preprocess the column
df['Clean'] = df['SUPPLIER_NAME'].apply(cleansing_special_characters)


                            # step 1 cleanining

# ##for n_gram fingerprint algorithm
###########################################################################################

df['n_gram_fingerprint_n2'] = df['Clean'].apply(lambda x : fingerprinter(x.replace(" ","")).get_ngram_fingerprint(n=2))


## generate tag_id for every unique generated n_gram_fingerprint
d = defaultdict(lambda: len(d))
df['tag_idn']=[d[x] for x in df['n_gram_fingerprint_n2']]

###########################################################################################

#drop n_gram column
df.drop(columns=['n_gram_fingerprint_n2'], inplace=True)

# make copy to create group of tag_id
df1 = df[['SUPPLIER_NAME','tag_idn']]


# drop SUPPLIER_NAME column , we have tag_id's now
df.drop(columns=['SUPPLIER_NAME'], inplace=True)

# group df with tag_id with selecting minimum 
#group = df.groupby('tag_id').min().reset_index()
group = df.loc[df["Clean"].str.len().groupby(df["tag_idn"]).idxmax()]

# join both the data frames group(unique) and main data
df_merge = pd.merge(df1,group, on=['tag_idn'])


# # output excel file
df_merge.to_excel('Output_File.xlsx', index = False)
```

This is what the outpout data in an excel file looks like

[image: Supplier Name Cleaned]